# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Future<Useri, is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    class FirebaseAuthService implements AuthBase {
      final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;    
      @override
      Future<Userim> currentUser() async {
        try {
          User? user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
          return _userFromFirebase(user);
        } catch (e) {
          print('ERROR CURRENT USER' + e.toString());
        }
      }    
      Userim _userFromFirebase(User? user) {
        if (user == null) {
          return null;
        } else {
          return Userim(userID: user.uid);
        }
      }
    }

class Userim{
      final String userID;    
      Userim({required this.userID});
    }
```

In my code when using Flutter Firebase currentUser() in the method :

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Future<Userim>', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
```

i am getting the error.
also return null

```
A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the method '_userFromFirebase' because it has a return type of 'Userim'
```

Comment: `_firebaseAuth.currentUser` is returning null. Check this code passage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your return value to be nullable just add ? to its type declaration:

`Future<Userim?> currentUser() async... etc.`

and in

`Userim? _userFromFirebase(User? user) {... etc.`